# How do I smooth a ternary plot by point value rather than by point density in R?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I'm using R's `ggtern` package to create a lovely ternary plot that presents some data I have generated with a simulation model. I'd attach a plot to this post to show you what the plot looks like, but I don't have sufficient reputation to do that. Instead, I will paste code below that can replicate all of the essential features of my plot. As a disclaimer, I am very new to `ggplot` graphics, so I'm sure my code is a mess.

My question is pretty simple (I think)--How could I amend my code so as to smooth the values of "Fruit Set" (`make1df$Value`), thereby revealing the overall pattern/trend in the data? I'm thinking even something as simple as a weighted average with all neighboring points could even suffice. So far, I have only been able to figure out how to smooth over the density of points rather than the values associated with those points (using functions like `stat_smooth2d()` and the like).

Keep in mind that what I'm providing below is "fake data;" this is not how I have generated the data I actually intend to plot. The `compositions` function used below is in the`partitions` package.

Code:

```
library(plyr) # for rename
library(ggtern) # for ggtern
library(partitions) # for compositions
make1 = as.matrix(compositions(50, 3, include.zero=TRUE))
make1 = t(make1)
make1df = as.data.frame(make1)
make1df = rename(make1df, c("V1"="H", "V2"="B", "V3"="S"))
seq1 = seq(from=0.24, to=0.41, length=1326)
make1df$Value = rep(0, 1326)
for (i in 1:1326) {
  make1df$Value[i] = seq1[i] + rnorm(1, 0, 0.03)
}

ggtern(make1df, aes(H, B, S)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=make1df$Value), size=4.5) + 
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "pink", high = "darkblue") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.tern.text=element_text(size=24), 
        axis.tern.showtitles=FALSE, 
        axis.tern.arrow.text=element_text(size=22),
        axis.tern.arrow=element_line(size=1.5, color="black"), 
        axis.tern.vshift=unit(3, "line"),
        legend.title = element_text(size=24),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 24), 
        legend.key.size = unit(3.5, "lines")) +
  labs(x = "% HONEY BEES",y = "% BUMBLE BEES", z = "% SMALL BEES", 
       colour="MEAN \nFRUIT SET")
```

[image]

Comment: I believe you will have to calculated the weighted averages yourself, *before* plotting. If a point has coordinates (h, b, s), what are the coordinates of its neighbours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will have to calculated your weighted average outside of the `ggtern` call first.

You will have to calculate your average appropriately.
Here I'm merely assuming (possibly incorrectly, ternary coordinates do my head in!):

- the neighbours of `(h, s, b)` are `(h, s +-1, b -+1)`, `(h +-1, s -+1, b)` and `(h +-1, s, b -+1)` (where the `+-` and `-+` are in opposite orders, so if it's `s+1` then it must be `b-1` so that the coordinates all add to the same constant.
- your `make1df` *only* has valid ternary coordinates in it (i.e. `H+S+B` is constant for all coordinates)
- the weighted mean is taken over `(h, s, b)` plus its neighbours as defined previously.
- note that if your `(h, s, b)` values are continuous (e.g. things like `(.5, .5, 49)` are possible), the "neighbourhood" defined previously is all points "within distance 1" of `(h, s, b)`

Let me mention again that ternary coordinates do my head in, so you may have to adjust the definition above accordingly.

So, first add a column `wAvg` where we look up the neighbours of each coordinate and calculate the mean `Value`. The `abs(H-h) <= 1` etc is a trick/shorthand for finding the coordinates that are within distance 1 of `(h,s,b)`. The `Value[...]` grabs the `Values` of those neighbours, and `mean` calculates the mean. The `mapply` just ensures we do this for each row. The only reason I used `mutate` here was to save writing a lot of `make1df$`.

```
# calculate avg
make1df <- mutate(make1df, wAvg=mapply(function (h, b, s) {
  # includes (h,b,s) & its neighbours
  mean(Value[abs(H-h)<= 1 & abs(S-s) <= 1 & abs(B-b) <= 1])
}, H, B, S))
```

Then you do your plot, with `wAvg` as your `colour` rather than `Value`. (note: you can do `aes(colour=wAvg)` rather than `aes(colour=make1df$wAvg)`):

```
ggtern(make1df, aes(H, B, S)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=wAvg), size=4.5) + 
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "pink", high = "darkblue") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.tern.text=element_text(size=24), 
        axis.tern.showtitles=FALSE, 
        axis.tern.arrow.text=element_text(size=22),
        axis.tern.arrow=element_line(size=1.5, color="black"), 
        axis.tern.vshift=unit(3, "line"),
        legend.title = element_text(size=24),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 24), 
        legend.key.size = unit(3.5, "lines")) +
  labs(x = "% HONEY BEES",y = "% BUMBLE BEES", z = "% SMALL BEES", 
       colour="MEAN \nFRUIT SET")
```

[image]

If you wanted to increase the 'neighbourhood' radius you would just change the 1 to the new radius.

Comment: Let me see if I can answer my own questions: `mutate` is just a more powerful `transform`--it remakes an object in some specified way. In this case, it's just making a new named column (`wAvg`) therein. `mapply` is a more specific `apply` in that it applies a specified function (`mean`, in this case) to all relevant entries of an object. `h`, `b`, and `s` are actually specified in that they are given as arguments to `mutate` in the form of the original `H`, `B`, and `S` vectors at the very end of the call to `mutate`.

Comment: Mutate and transform both add columns to a dataframe, but mutate lets you use columns already created in subsequent definitions. e.g. `mutate(iris, x=1, y=x+1)` works but `transform` won't be able to find `x` when creating the `y` column. The help says that sometimes mutate is faster, so I just use it all the time. `apply` is quite different to `mapply`. `apply` works on 2D things (apply FUN to each column, or to each ROW). `mapply` is like `sapply` but where you have multiple arguments you wish to vectorise over. The specified function is not `mean`; it's the `function (h, b, s) {...}`.

Comment: You don't actually need to use `mutate`: you could do `make1df$wAvg <- mapply(....)` with `make1df$H` etc instead of `H`; I just used `mutate` so I could drop all the `make1df$`.